# how to vertically sum a range of dynamic variables in sas?

Tags: sas

I have a dataset in SAS in which the months would be dynamically updated each month. I need to calculate the sum vertically each month and paste the sum below, as shown in the image.

Proc means/ proc summary and proc print are not doing the trick for me.

I was given the following code before:

```
`%let month = month name;
%put &month.;

data new_totals;
set Final_&month. end=end;  
&month._sum + &month._final;    
/*feb_sum + &month._final;*/
output;                
if end then do;         
measure = 'Total';    
&month._final = &month._sum;  
/*Feb_final = feb_sum;*/
output;               
end;
drop &month._sum;   
run; `
```

The problem is this has all the months hardcoded, which i don't want. I am not too familiar with loops or arrays, so need a solution for this, please.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFz8F.png)

Comment: Do you want a SAS data set with these values or is this for reporting purposes?

Comment: I don't understand. Your photograph just looks like a printout.  Try `proc print; var _all_; sum _numeric_;run;`

Comment: @draycut I need it as a data step for the data needs to be used in a lot of other steps later on.

Answer (score 1):

It may be better to use a reporting procedure such as `PRINT` or `REPORT` to produce the desired output.

```
data have;
  length group $20;
  do group = 'A', 'B', 'C';
    array month_totals jan2020 jan2019 feb2020 feb2019 mar2019 apr2019 may2019 jun2019 jul2019 aug2019 sep2019 oct2019 oct2019 nov2019 dec2019;
    do over month_totals;
      month_totals  = 10 + floor(rand('uniform', 60));
    end;
    output;
  end;
run;

ods excel file='data_with_total_row.xlsx';

proc print noobs data=have;
  var group ;
  sum jan2020--dec2019;  
run;

proc report data=have;
  columns group jan2020--dec2019;
  define group / width=20;
  rbreak after / summarize;
  compute after;
    group = 'Total';
  endcomp;
run;

ods excel close;
```

[image]

**Data structure**

The data sets you are working with are 'difficult' because the date aspect of the data is actually in the metadata, i.e. the column name.  An even better approach, in SAS, is too have a categorical data with columns

- `group` (categorical role)
- `month` (categorical role)
- `total` (continuous role)

Such data can be easily filtered with a `where` clause, and reporting procedures such as `REPORT` and `TABULATE` can use the `month` variable in a `class` statement.

Example:

```
data have;
  length group $20;
  do group = 'A', 'B', 'C';
    do _n_ = 0 by 1 until (month >= '01feb2020'd);
      month = intnx('month', '01jan2018'd, _n_);
      total = 10 + floor(rand('uniform', 60));
      output;
    end;
  end;
  format month monyy5.;
run;

proc tabulate data=have;
  class group month;
  var total;
  table 
    group all='Total'
    ,
    month='' * total='' * sum=''*f=comma9.
  ;
  where intck('month', month, '01feb2020'd) between 0 and 13;
run;


proc report data=have;
  column group (month,total);
  define group / group;
  define month / '' across order=data ;
  define total / '' ;

  where intck('month', month, '01feb2020'd) between 0 and 13;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic way. Borrowed sample data from Richard.

```
data have;
  length group $20;
  do group = 'A', 'B';
    array months jan2020 jan2019 feb2020 feb2019 mar2019 apr2019 may2019 jun2019 jul2019 aug2019 sep2019 oct2019 oct2019 nov2019 dec2019;
    do over months;
      months  = 10 + floor(rand('uniform', 60, 1));
    end;
    output;
  end;
run;

proc summary data=have;
    var _numeric_;
    output out=temp(drop=_:) sum=;
run;

data want;
    set have temp (in=t);
    if t then group='Total';
run;
```